# Auto populating all the fields of an infopath form

Tags: search, infopath, auto-populate

I am working on an infopath form for a sharepoint list where there are defect details to be added to the list. There is a field to input defect id if it is an existing defect. So I want that when a user enters the defect id and presses enter, it should search the list and autopopulate rest of the fields with that defect details.

Can anyone please advice me how do I do this. Any assistance would be really appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a secondary data connection to your defects list and while creating the data connection select **Get data** from SharePoint list. Then select your all your relevant column like **Defect ID, Defect Details**, and so on. Now the secondary data connection is ready.

Create two textbox columns, one to pass the input another one to display the result based on the input pass in the first text box (Defect ID).

Step 1:

Select the **defect details text box** in the form.

Step2:

Click on the Default value **Fx** button.

Step3:

Click on the insert **field or Group**

Step4:

Select your **secondary data connection** from the data connection list.

Step5:

Select the **Defect Details** from the Data Fields section

Step6:

Click on the **filter** button

Step7:

In the filter add **selectDefectID** (from list secondary data connection) -eq "**DefectID**(from the form textbox - where you will enter that textbox). Click 5 times OK, one after another.

Finally, filter should look like below:

```
Defect_x0020_Details[DefectID = SearchDefectByID]
```

[image: Display InfoPath filed based on the other field]

Output:

[image: Based on dropdown selection set textbox value in Infopath form2]

Comment: This is amazing.. Thank you very much, Habibur. Appreciate all your help! :)

Comment: Hello, This works on all the controls like text field or drop down list but somehow doesn't work on people picker. Is there any way to populate people picker field as well?